# How do I add text after a command has run using /tellraw in minecraft pc?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This is a confusing question but I'll try my best to explain what I need help with.

So this is the command I'm using

```
/tellraw @p ["Would you like to Teleport?",{"text": " Yes ","color": "green","bold": "true","clickEvent": { "action": "run_command","value": "/tp @p -8188.449 64 7415.522 "},"hoverEvent":{"action": "show_text","value":{"text": "Confirm"}}},{"text": " No ","color": "red","bold": "true","clickEvent":{"action": "run_command","value": "/tellraw @p {\"text\":\"Come back when you want to teleport\"}"},"hoverEvent":{"action":"show_text","value":{"text":"Cancel"}}}]
```

Works great but I want to add something more to it. After the the command `/tp`, I want to add more text that says something like "teleporting..please wait" but I'm not sure how to execute that. Whether I need another command block or there's a data tag to add more text after that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `setblock` command, using a redstone block, instead of teleporting the player right away. The block would be placed next to some redstone, which would trigger a command block to say "teleporting", and run to a line of repeaters to create delay, which is what I assume you want. At the end, have it trigger two command blocks: One to teleport the player, the other to remove the redstone block, to ensure that this would work more than once. Here's a simple schematic:

```
     C2
C1   ^
R>>>>+>>C3
```

Where `R` is where the redstone block would be placed, `C1` is the command block that would have the command to tell the player, `C2` is the command block that destroys the redstone block, `C3` is the command block that actually teleports the player. `>>` being a right-facing repeater, `^` being an up-facing repeater and `+` being redstone dust. You could also take advantage of the Scoreboard system so the command block teleports the correct player.

Comment: i'm not very good with redstone, but I will try it out. thank you!